# Add Breadcrumb to search results

Tags: search

Please i need help in the matter below  : 
I want to add breadcrumb to each element of the search results .
I didn't find any option to enable that in the search setting , I'm using the search module of Drupal 7 .
Could someone help me in achieving that?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: There's no out of the box solution for this. You may need a different display for search only, that you can achieve with Views. Maybe create a page that displays exposed filters and customize the fields inside the view, adding relationships required to mimic breadcrumbs. That's what popsup in my mind right now. Not really a complete solution but an idea.